# changed crontab, jobs run at old AND new time now

Tags: linux, cron

I did a non-best practice on `/etc/crontab` and manually changed it to run a daily cron job at a specific time, initially for testing so I could make sure it fired off correctly.

`/etc/crontab` looked like this:

```
42 18 * * * root /etc/cron.daily/cronjob1
-*/15 * * * * root {built-in out-of-the-box crontab entry}
```

Once I was satisfied the job ran as expected, I removed that entry from `/etc/crontab`, restarted crond, and added a new crontab as root using "`crontab -e`"

```
00 00 * * * /bin/sh /etc/cron.customjobs/cronjob1
```

"new" `/etc/crontab`:

```
-*/15 * * * * root {built-in out-of-the-box crontab entry}
```

Since this change, the job runs at 1842 AND at midnight every day. The system has even been rebooted at least twice since then and still the job runs at the old time. I'm not sure why the 1842 start time is stuck in the system somewhere and I am going crazy trying to track this down. SLES15 if that helps

I've tried looking in `/var/spool/cron/tabs` and only the one I manually created using `crontab -e` is listed there. I'm not sure what else is supposed to be holding the timer that isn't in the crontab(s) anymore.

Comment: Why you have dash (`-`) in from on `*/15`?

Comment: That's the way the crontab installed itself, I didn't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally there is default cron entry (possibly found in /`etc/cron.d/` or provided by anacron when not in `/etc/crontab`)  that runs all scripts/executables found in the `/etc/cron.daily` directory.

That would typically be the job specification that will execute:

```
/etc/cron.daily/cronjob1
          ˆˆˆˆˆ
```

Your root crontab runs a ***different script***:

```
/etc/cron.customjobs/cronjob1
          ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
```

That would be a reason why cronjob1 runs twice

Comment: Also - don't forget that there are separate crontabs per user.

Comment: I thought I mentioned it, but the cron.daily job was moved to cron.customjobs, so the script only appears once yet runs twice

Comment: Also, when I double checked, there *was* an entry in /etc/cron.d for the job which I completely overlooked before